# Not working mark(0) and reset() of BufferedReader in my code

Tags: java

In the following code i used mark(0) and reset() methods to read the text file from top to bottom 5 times. but not working please help me.

```
 package com.narasimha;
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;
 public class Attempts {

 public static void main(String args[]) {

     int count=0;
     BufferedReader file;
     HashSet<String> ualist;
     List<String> salist,ssclist,splist;
     String ualine,saline,sscline,spline;
     long sum=0;
     double avg;

    try{    
        file=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("KAR_UBONA_UBONACT15_20150929_20150930_FEEDBACK.txt"));
        file.mark(0);

    //1.No of Attempts
        while(file.readLine()!=null){
            count++;
        }
          System.out.println("No of Attempts\t"+count);
         file.reset();
          count=0;
    //2. No of uniq Attempts
          file.mark(0);
          ualist=new HashSet<String>(); 
              while((ualine=file.readLine())!=null){
                    String array[]=ualine.split(",");
                    ualist.add(array[0]);
                  }
                  for(String ua:ualist){
                        count++;
                   }
            System.out.println("No of Uniq Attempts\t"+count);
             file.reset();
            count=0;
    //3. Successful Attempts
           file.mark(0);
           salist=new ArrayList<String>();
                while((saline=file.readLine())!=null){
                    String array[]=saline.split(",");
                        if(!(array[1].equals("0")))
                            salist.add(array[1]);
                            sum=sum+Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
                    }
                   for(String sa:salist){
                       count++;
                   }
                   avg=sum/count;
            System.out.println("No of Successful  Attempts\t"+count);
            //Average Mou of Successful Calls
            System.out.println("Avg Mou of Successful Calls\t"+avg);
             file.reset();
            count=0;
    //4.Song Selected Calls
           file.mark(0);
           ssclist=new ArrayList<String>();
                while((sscline=file.readLine())!=null){
                    String array[]=sscline.split(",");
                        if(!(array[2].equals("\\N")))
                            ssclist.add(array[2]);
                    }
                   for(String ssc:ssclist){
                       count++;
                   }
        System.out.println("No of Song Selected Calls\t"+count);
         file.reset();
        count=0;
    //5.calls where atleast one song was played
         file.mark(0);
           splist=new ArrayList<String>();
                while((spline=file.readLine())!=null){
                    String array[]=spline.split(",");
                        if(!(array[3].equals("")))
                            splist.add(array[3]);
                    }
                   for(String sp:splist){
                       count++;
                   }
        System.out.println("Songs where atleast on song was played\t"+count);

          file.close();

    }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.print("Sorry! Unable to connect to the file");
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Specify your problem.

Comment: You do realize that `mark(0);` doesn't mean that the `mark` will be at position `0` in the file?

Comment: To be honest, it is quite pointless to use `#mark` and `#reset` for re-reading _whole_ files, since it isn't designed for large amounts of bytes. Just create a new BufferedReader.

Comment: Have you actually read the documentation of [`BufferedReader.mark`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#mark-int-). Hint: the `0` does not mean what you think it means.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a misinterpretation of the meaning of the parameter of the method `mark(int readAheadLimit)`. As javadoc explains the number to specify is the number of chars that may be read while still preserving the mark. This number also define the new size of the buffer (if it is smaller). Because the buffer is in the heap you should use it carefully and for suitable situation (and yours seems to be not).

If you have to scan a file more than one time you should do the open/read/close cycle more times.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this much easier in your while-loop:

```
String line = null;
while((line = file.readLine()) != null) { //this gives line the String of one line of the file
    String[] array = line.split(",");
    ualist = new HashSet<String>();
    ualist.add(array[0]);
    salist = new ArrayList<String>();
    salist.add(array[1]); 
    // and so on
```

You can then specify separate methods your deriving the average value and so on.